# Azure Mobile Services PullAsync() Not Filling Sync Table

Tags: c#, sqlite, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

So I have a remote table called `Profile` that has multiple entries made already. Now I'm trying to integrate offline capabilities into my application. As of right now I'm having issues with `PushAsync` and `PullAsync` methods in my code.

I would like to be able to copy all the data from my remote table into my local table just by calling `PullAsync`, and although it doesn't throw any exceptions it also doesn't populate my table. Here's an example of what I mean.

```
        var db = new SQLiteConnection("syncstoreTEMP.db");
        var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("syncstoreTEMP.db");
        store.DefineTable<Profile>();
        MobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store).Wait();
        var remoteValues = MobileService.GetTable<Profile>()
            .ToListAsync()
            .Result;
        MobileService.GetSyncTable<Profile>()
            .PullAsync(null, MobileService.GetSyncTable<Profile>().CreateQuery())
            .Wait();
        var localValues = MobileService.GetSyncTable<Profile>()
            .ToListAsync()
            .Result;
```

When I run this code `remoteValues` has a total length of 5, but `localValues` still shows 0 entries even after issuing a Pull from remote. How can I get the sync table to match my remote table?

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that you're not getting any exceptions, but you seem to be creating two connections to your local store. You should *not* have the line for new SQLiteConnection, only the line that creates the MobileServiceSQLiteStore.

Here's a tutorial that walks through how to set things up: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-xamarin-ios-get-started-offline-data/

I also recommend that you add a DelegatingHandler to your MobileServiceClient in order to log all of the requests and responses. Then you can see exactly what's going wrong. Here's a sample that shows this, and also includes a logging extension to the SQLite store so you can see exactly what is happening locally: https://github.com/paulbatum/FieldEngineerLite/blob/master/FieldEngineerLite.Client/FieldEngineerLite/Helpers/LoggingHelpers.cs